# How to make Entity Framework to truncate time portion of DateTime value mapped to SQL date type?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have an Entity Framework model based on an existing database (also called "Code First from database"). The database contains a `movies` table with the following columns:

```
id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
name nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
releaseDate date NOT NULL
```

Note that `releaseDate` column has SQL data type `date`, so it *does not* contain time portion. Entity Framework maps this data type to CLR `DateTime` type that *does* contain time portion.

Now I am going to add a new `movie` to the database. Important part here is that my new `movie` has some time portion specified in its `releaseDate` property:

```
var movie = new movie
{
    name = "Hello World",
    releaseDate = DateTime.Now // releaseDate contains time portion
};
using (var context = new Model())
{
    context.movies.Add(movie);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
Console.WriteLine(movie.id);          // id field was updated automatically
Console.WriteLine(movie.releaseDate); // releaseDate was not updated and still contains time portion
```

Now my new `movie` is stored in the database, and, obviously, time portion of `releaseDate` was ignored — only date part was stored in the DB. However, if I look at the `movie.releaseDate`, the time portion is still there.

I am wondering, how consistent is that behavior? Why does not Entity Framework update `releaseDate` to set its time portion to `00:00:00`? Since it automatically populated the `movie.id` property with auto-generated primary key value, why doesn't it do similar thing for `releaseDate` property?

Is there any way to enforce Entity Framework to truncate time portion of `DateTime` value mapped to SQL `date` type?

Comment: Please note that EF would give you a `DataTime ` without the time if you retrieve the entity from the database. The reason you have the time in your case is that this is an entity that you created yourself, and assigned the `releaseDate` yourself to a `DateTime` that has time.

Comment: @YacoubMassad I understand that, just wondering, why entity was not updated? I do not want to read it from the database or to reset the time portion manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF only updates the auto generated primary key. It doesn't load the whole entity back.

If you run a SQl Server trace you'll see that it performs an INSERT followed by a SELECT of only the primary key. In the example below I have a table Orders.

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [Purchasing].[Orders]([ClientCode], [OrderDate])
VALUES (@0, @1)
SELECT [OrderId]
FROM [Purchasing].[Orders]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [OrderId] = scope_identity()',N'@0 nvarchar(max) ,@1 datetime2(7)',@0=N'X',@1='2015-11-30 15:11:36.4326217'
```